# How can I remove my GitHub Bot from my GitHub "Following" Page?

Tags: github, automation, bots

I have a public repository that receives frequent commits by a GitHub Bot, but each of these commits is shown on my "Following"-Page, even though I do not follow the bot. How can I prevent the spam? Blocking the bot is not an option, since it wouldn't be able to push to my repository anymore.

[image: Preview]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best (and only) option is to ignore the repository. The default looks like this:
[image]

If you own the repository, you automatically watch it..

When you click on it, you can select a few options, sadly you cannot block activities from a specific user/bot, but you can select other options that may suit you:
[image]

I the repository is not actively used by people (like the new readme profile front page) then you can simply choose "Ignore", otherwise I would recommend choosing the first one, "Participating and @mentions". (Although you will miss some contributions).